# Glassfish request compression

Tags: java, glassfish, jax-ws

We have a legacy app that uses Java Web Services (JAX-WS) and runs on Glassfish 4.1.1. We want to implement compression of both the response and request. (We know that compressed requests can be a security risk but we are willing to accept this because the clients are all internal.) Turning on the GF setting for compression only compresses the response. If I send a compressed request body I get an error that indicates the SOAP message contained an invalid character, which tells me that GF did not decompress the request body.

Since GF won't automatically decompress the request I have been trying to modify the legacy app itself to do the decompression. I have tried the following:

- A SOAP message handler. This does not work because the handler is invoked too late; at that point the unmarshalling of the SOAP message has already failed, because the unmarshaller received binary data.
- A servlet filter. I tried setting up one that was invoked on any URL, but it never trips for the web service calls. I am not too familiar with the plumbing here, but it does not appear that the web service is implemented as a servlet.

My next option is to try setting up a proxy server that takes the raw request, unzips it, and forwards it to the web service.

Before I go down that path, does anyone have a simpler recommendations? Is what I'm try to do even possible? Much thanks in advance!

Comment: *"If I send a compressed request body"* Are you correctly specifying the `Content-Encoding` request header when you do that? If not, how would you expect the server to know that the request is compressed? --- Also remember, the headers are not compressed, only the payload.

Comment: Yes, this was tested via Postman, which allows you to provide a zip file as the request body, and the request headers included "accept-encoding" = "gzip, deflate"

Comment: I also added a request header "Content-Encoding" = "gzip", but that still doesn't work (I get an error "Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: XML reader error: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x8b (at char #2, byte #-1)")

Comment: *Hint:* A zip file is not a `gzip` file. Zip and gzip are two *different* file formats.

Comment: Thank you. I confirm that I created the compressed body using gzip on linux. We've also tried SoapUI as the client (it supports compressed requests natively) and get the same error.

Comment: I've been having the same problem. Hopefully someone can help